# How to remove headers from BrowseFragment?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, browsefragment

I am working on an android TV app and I am using the leanback library.

I want to customize the app layout "BrowseFragment". I want to remove the header view and only display the card list "rows".

Is it possible to do that or is there any other solution to achieve that?

[I want to remove that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yiGb.jpg)

Comment: You mean the header which are showing above rows ? Can you updates screen shot exactly ?

Comment: I want do delete the left side blue color, this side contains the headers of rows

Comment: You mean whole left side part you need to remove ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the HeaderState like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED); // Add this line
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but if i do that the rows disabled also ! I want do delete the left side blue color.

Comment: try HEADERS_HIDDEN

Comment: It works but the event between headers and rows still exist(the headers is hidden just one loaded)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this

Comment: @BillelBmsd, ebr answered worked for me. When I call setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED); it disabled the headers and the rows were present. 
Weird, in the sample app google has provided they are calling in this onActivityCreated(), not sure if disabling worked for them.

Comment: I am trying with both HEADERS_DISABLED and HEADERS_HIDDEN in OnActivityCreated() but the rows are also getting disabled.. can u give me a solution for this

Answer (score 12):

The above call actually needs to be in the OnCreate method instead of OnActivityCreated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

```
/** The headers fragment is enabled and hidden by default. */
```

**HEADERS_HIDDEN**

```
/** The headers fragment is disabled and will never be shown. */
```

**HEADERS_DISABLED**

OnCreate, you have to set the Header:

```
    setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED); //To Diable the Header

    setHeadersState(HEADERS_HIDDEN); //To Hide the Header
```

Answer (score 1):

When you change the setHeaderState(HEADERS_DISABLED), the rows would be disabled and hidden too. 
One way to do it is setHeaderPresenterSelector()

```
private void setupUIElements() {

    setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED);

    setHeaderPresenterSelector(new PresenterSelector() {
        @Override
        public Presenter getPresenter(Object item) {
            return new CustomPresenter();
        }
    });
}
```

you just need to override the getPresenter() method, and return new customized presenter that you need to implement.